# Serilog Save to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, logging, serilog

I have a console application in .NET 6 to log using Serilog to a SQL Server database. Find my code snippet below:

`Program.cs`:

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer;
using SerilogExample.Repo;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;

var configProvider = new ConfigProvider();
var serilogConnectionString = configProvider.GetSerilogConnectionString();
var serilogTableName = configProvider.GetSerilogTableName();
var configuration = configProvider.GetConfiguration();

var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
{
    AdditionalColumns = new Collection<SqlColumn>
    {
        new SqlColumn("UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    }
};

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(serilogConnectionString,
                sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                {
                    TableName = serilogTableName,
                    AutoCreateSqlTable = true,
                    SchemaName = "dbo"
                },
                null, null, LogEventLevel.Information, null, columnOptions: columnOptions, null, null)
                .CreateLogger();

try
{
    Log.Information("Starting application");

    // Simulate some application work
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Log.Information($"Processing item {i}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulating work
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(ex, "An error occurred");
}
finally
{
    Log.Information("Shutting down");
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "My database connection string goes here",
    "TableName": "LogsTest"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          //"connectionString": "My database connection string goes here",
          "connectionString": "My database connection string goes here",
          "tableName": "LogsTest",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IConfigProvider
{
    string GetSerilogConnectionString();
    string GetSerilogTableName();

    IConfiguration GetConfiguration();
}
```

Concrete class:

```
public class ConfigProvider : IConfigProvider
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ConfigProvider()
    {
        _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();
    }

    public string GetSerilogConnectionString()
    {
        //return _configuration.GetSection("Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:connectionString").Value;
        return _configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value;
    }

    public string GetSerilogTableName()
    {
        //return _configuration.GetSection("Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:tableName").Value;
        return _configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:TableName").Value;
    }

    public IConfiguration GetConfiguration()
    {
        return _configuration;
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I run this code, no table was created and as such nothing is logged. What am I doing wrong?

I have refactored the code for simplicity and walked through it line by line but when I check my SQL Server database, no table was created and nothing was logged.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer documentation](https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver)? In the `appsettings.json` file have you tried nesting the `autoCreateSqlTable` and `tableName` properties inside a `sinkOptionsSection`?

Comment: By that, I'm assuming you meant something like this:
sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                {
                    TableName = serilogTableName,
                    AutoCreateSqlTable = true,
                    SchemaName = "dbo"
                },
You can provide a snippet if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: By that I mean you should read the documentation linked above. In your `appsettings.json` file the `autoCreateSqlTable` and `tableName` properties **do not** belong at the `Args` level so they're having no effect.